# If re-booked from a flight to a train, can one claim the airport taxes back?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cancellations, refunds, taxes

Recently flew GOT-DUS-HAM (booked directly with the airline), whereby the DUS-HAM leg was cancelled last-minute and I got an open rail voucher.

Can I get the airport taxes of the second flight refunded?

Comment: German domestic departure tax is less than €8. My guess is that you can't reclaim it. What do the terms and conditions on your booking say?

Comment: They got you there, all airlines and airports are in financial problems. I think it is better not to bother.

Comment: So the airline actually got you to your destination? You got upgraded to a train? And you want money back? Did I get this right?

Comment: @KristvanBesien I didn't get the flight, period, which the relevant taxes are dependent on. Re-booking me to a train was their obligation, not a gesture of goodwill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: went through geld-fuer-flug.de and they've paid me €31.83, 90% of the refundable amount (they usually pay 75% but I found a promo code to get an extra 20%).

Answer (score 4):

In theory any charges and taxes which were levied can be claimed back from the airline.
In practice however it depends upon the airline and their T&Cs.

Often in such cases their T&Cs might state that certain levies will not be refunded, or may only be refunded on certain types of tickets.

Even then most airlines will levy an administration fee for processing any such claims.  This may vary from 20 -> 50 -> 100 EUROS, which again might vary depending on the type of claim and the type of ticket.

As such, then normally trying to make a claim might mean that you get nothing back, very little, or could end up out of pocket!

So you need to check the T&Cs of your airline in detail.  But my guess would be that for such a route the fees are not worth your while to try to reclaim.